# How to fetch Data from mysql DB table if at some places foreign id is 0 and i am applying inner join using that table

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have 4 master tables called as country, industry, size, type and 1 another table called Company Data.

In Windows form application i have 1 form Company Data in that there are some Text boxes and dropdown lists. In dropdown lists the data coming from master tables. Now when i am saving Company Data form information i am saving the selected ids of master tables but that dropdown lists are not mandatory fields so when that field is not selected i am inserting 0 in Company data table. When i am fetching the data from Company Data table i am applying inner join with  4 masters but if at any record in Company data master id is zero the data is not showing

Comment: Without having any code snippet in your question, I assume that you are using an `inner join` in your SQL-statement. You can switch to using `left join` instead of `inner join`, then your data should be shown. Maybe you can provide a code snippet of your SQL statemnt.

Comment: You probably want a `LEFT JOIN`. See also https://sqlperformance.com/2021/10/database-design/bad-habits-avoiding-null

Comment: Thank you for quick response, your answer solved my problem needed left join

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.